# Single word for "time spent"

Tags: time

Is there a single word for an amount of time spent on a task for example?
More specific than duration?

Comment: And what is wrong with duration, which does the job, it seems.

Comment: you may try to use 'elapsed'. The usage is generally 'time elapsed' but there's hardly anything else than time that can be elapsed, so there's no ambiguity in "elapsed: 5 minutes".

Comment: @JasperLoy: context is labor hours invested. Can't think of a more specific context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a single word, except maybe *hours.* People talk about the *hours* they worked on something. "How many hours do you have in this week?"

I saw that one time-tracking site called time spent on a task "active time," and another called it "tasktime" (one word, but coined, I think). In an office setting, it could also be called "billable time" or "billable hours."

Comment: Sometimes this is measured in _man-hours_, and least in the O.P.'s context.

Answer (score 4):

I did my [stint](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stint) in the kitchen yesterday.

> a period of time spent at a particular activity

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning, but it's usually applied to unpleasant activities, and it falutes a little low for official payroll accounting. Still, _stint_ might work in the particular context; only the OP can say.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really ***spend*** *time*. You can spend *money*, though, and you can use the **[Time is Money](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf)** metaphor theme.

In the paper linked above, the object of *spend* is called "perceived duration", because it's general over all uses of the metaphor. However, in a specific task-oriented time accounting context -- where Time really ***is*** Money -- I think self-explanatory labels like **"Total time spent by all workers on task *X*"** or **"Mean daily time spent by worker *Y* on task *Z*"** work far better than searching out the perfect one-word label. If they don't fit the space available for labels, give some thought to priorities.

Executive Summary: If it's not obvious to you, it won't be obvious to your readers, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can *[while](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while?show=3&t=1340202135)* time:

> : to cause to pass especially without boredom or in a pleasant manner —usually >used with away