# Usage of "spend time"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I live in Japan and have noticed that a lot Japanese people are prone to say/write "I spent a good time with my friends/family/kids." It has always rubbed me the wrong way, and when I can, I usually explain that "I HAD a good time with..." is the proper expression. Google ngram confirmed my belief that it's weird and/or grammatically incorrect, as the usage of "spend a good time" doesn't exist. But on the other hand, it seems perfectly normal to say "I spent a long time / a lot of time with..." So my question is, is there a grammatical explanation for this, or is it just one of the many weird quirks of English?

Comment: It's a rule of logic, not an idiosyncrasy. Spend is how you pay out money, effort, time. So you can spend the day, spend a morning, spend a long time. But a good time is not a period of time to pay out, it's a judgment of what that time felt like *to have, to show someone, to miss*.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks!

Comment: See the sadly missed Professor Lawler's explanation of the 'time is money' metaphor at [single word for time spent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71838/single-word-for-time-spent/71849#71849) and link. A ['conceptual'](https://www.thoughtco.com/metaphor-figure-of-speech-and-thought-1691385) (and prevalent, 'conventional') metaphor. "I've earned a break." 'Paying back one's debt to society by 80 hours of community service.'